# Else than current location, how to take user input from google map in android?(not the current location)

Tags: android, google-maps

I searched most questions and googled much, but all I find is how to input current location.

I want to make an app where the user can input a location from google map, and that location can be anywhere (not just his current location).
If anyone can direct me in right path, even a clue will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to click on any place on the map and select it.

Read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events) how to do that.